# Почему не отображаются свойства политики AD после миграции?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Была произведена миграция контроллера домена с Windows 2003 R2 SP2 на Windows 2012. Ошибок не было. И потребовалось изменить правило политики для группы компьютеров. Правлило "Выполнять только указанные приложения Windows". Проблема в том, что в windows 2012 в редактировании правила не отображается список программ. В 2012 список видно только при выборе политики во вкладке "параметры". В тоже время на 2003 все отображается. Почему?